# Unable to scroll image using scroll view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing this weird problem with scroll view in swift, The image does not scroll even after defining scroll view in the file, I have also added zooming and it worked fine. Please help me with this
https://pastebin.com/1uC3fqHG

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewController: UIViewController
{
    var imageURL: URL? {
        didSet {
            image = nil
            if view.window != nil {
                fetchImage()
            }
        }
    }

    private func fetchImage() {
        if let url = imageURL {
            let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            if let imageData = urlContents {
                image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageURL = URL(string: "http://www.lamborghini.com/en-en/sites/en-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/share%20img/huracan-coupe-facebook-og.jpg")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if image == nil {
            fetchImage()
        }

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {

            scrollView.delegate = self
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.03
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
            scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }


    fileprivate var imageView = UIImageView()

    private var image: UIImage? {
        get{
            return imageView.image
        }
        set{
            imageView.image = newValue
            imageView.sizeToFit()
            scrollView?.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
        }
    }
}

extension ImageViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are adding the image to the view in viewDidLoad(). Remove `view.addSubview(imageView)` from the viewDidLoad() and all will be working perfectly.
**Code will become as follows**

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewController: UIViewController
{
    var imageURL: URL? {
        didSet {
            image = nil
            if view.window != nil {
                fetchImage()
            }
        }
    }

    private func fetchImage() {
        if let url = imageURL {
            let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            if let imageData = urlContents {
                image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageURL = URL(string: "http://www.lamborghini.com/en-en/sites/en-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/share%20img/huracan-coupe-facebook-og.jpg")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if image == nil {
            fetchImage()
        }

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {

            scrollView.delegate = self
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.03
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
            scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }


    fileprivate var imageView = UIImageView()

    private var image: UIImage? {
        get{
            return imageView.image
        }
        set{
            imageView.image = newValue
            imageView.sizeToFit()
            scrollView?.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
        }
    }
}

extension ImageViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be updating the content size and update the image view constraints Checkout this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122139/uiscrollview-tutorial)